# How to include two or more custom List Views in the same android app

Tags: android, android-listview

Actually I am trying to implement more than two list views in the same program, I have created a java file for implementing the custom list views and then have added 2 pages for trial with data , but the problem is the demo app is hanging a lot  on real device and the app contains a lot of images.

Comment: You might want to look into some ansynchronous image loading libraries. I'm having the hunch that loading the images is creating the performance bottleneck you are experiencing. Maybe this helps: http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-0

Answer (score 0):

If the list has a lot of images than you should consider processing the image in the background. In the link below there is a few example on how to do that.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html